# PDFKit rails 4 and bootstrap hangs with multiple pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I have a number of `<div class="row" >...</div>` in the index page of one of my models. When I use the middleware option (`localhost:3000/foos.pdf`) or via the `PDFKit.new(http://localhost:3000/foos.pdf)` method the `wkhtmltopdf` process hangs forever. From the console I can see that it tells me via the 2nd method that it starts hanging after the `"page 1/n"` status message.

When I set `print_media_type: true` in the PDFKit initializer file it works no problem but the boostrap formatting gets all messed up in the print view. (However it has no problems making a multi-page document that way).

Any ideas?

OS: Ubuntu 14.04
wkhtmltopdf version: 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt)
config points to this binary and not any bundled ones. (Doesn't change the problem either way though)

Comment: I have the same issue since I upgraded my app from Rails 3.x to 4.2.4. I already had print_media_type: true option set.